# Is there any way to find datastage change history?

Tags: datastage

If someone change something like parameter, routine name...etc in designer

Is there any way to find those history?

and also Is datastage support debugging mode? (Because, I want to find which job occurs error)

I can only see change history information about Monitoring Agent
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/change-history-monitoring-agent-datastage

Comment: Are you referring to the product in general or to one of your jobs?

Comment: one of my jobs. For example, If I change condition in nested condition activity, Is there anyway that I can find those change history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend adding an Annotation to each job to document recent changes incl. date, person who did the change and a rough description if the change.
This is easy and a proofen concept.
Also before changing a job - manual copy / historization of the job is an additional option.

You could also check the [integration of a Source Code Control system](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=control-source-infosphere-datastage-qualitystage-assets)

If you have none of the above there is no out of the box solution to figure out these changes.

Comment: If an older version copy of the job exists, you can compare jobs either directly in the designer or via command line %ds_client_classic%\diffapicmdline.exe